# Find latest record from list based on object property?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class `Test`

```
public class Test
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

List have below data

```
List<Test> lstTest = new List<Test>();
lstTest.Add(new Test() { Id = 1, Name = "Test 1", CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("05/05/2005"), ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("09/05/2005") });
lstTest.Add(new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "Test 2", CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("06/05/2005"), ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("07/05/2005") });
lstTest.Add(new Test() { Id = 3, Name = "Test 3", CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("08/05/2005"), ModifiedDate = null });
```

now I want to find a record which is updated last for example in the list of `Test` three records first record is latest updated because its modified date is latest so how can I find it?

now lets change scenario

```
lstTest.Add(new Test() { Id = 4, Name = "Test 4", CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10/05/2005"), ModifiedDate = null });
```

so 4th record is latest based on created date so how we can find 4th record
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could sort the list by date and use LINQ to get the record:

```
var latest = lstTest.OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedDate ?? x.CreatedDate).First();
```

Comment: Hi @fabjan there are possibility modified date will be null and when modified date is null then need to look in created date

Comment: @JasminSolanki Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `OrderBy` to sort by date (oldest first), then use `LastOrDefault` to get the last entry (or null if the collection contains no entries).

Use null coalescing operator `??` to handle any null values of ModifiedDate and use the CreationDate in this case for comparison.

```
Test lastEntry = lstTest
    .OrderBy(t => t.ModifiedDate ??  t.CreatedDate)
    .LastOrDefault();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8bvwqX)

Comment: Asking "latest updated because its modified date is latest". So order by ModifiedDate

Answer (score 0):

try this ... then you can find latest record.

```
var latestRecord = lstTest.OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedDate ?? x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code:

var latestrecord = lstTest.OrderByDescending(t => t.ModifiedDate)
                  .FirstOrDefault();